How can I shape-up a setup project for a .NET 6 / C# Windows Forms project to make it work?
I wrote a rather simple C# Solution in VS2022 on the basis of .NET 6.0. Consisting of a Main-project and some additional projects (= DLL's). To deploy my program I wish to use a setup.exe, so I added a Setup Project to my solution.
My question is: is there anybody who can explain how to fill in a proper Setup Project in .NET 6.0 is working? Thanks in advance.
For the main project, as well as each additional project I added 'Publish Items' in the target Application Folder. Thinking to be safe I run the setup. The result of this was bad.
Appearantly some parts of the installation were written in the Registry but the installation did not complete. It also appeared that installed parts of the application are now blocking a reinstall ("error: already installed").
While Windows - at the same time - does not recognize the application being installed (?!) because it didn't complete properly. And therefore I cannnot execute a deinstallation either.
So I'm stuck and documention on the internet is poor.
